# Java 7 on Debian squeeze

Tags: java, debian-squeeze

I have Debian GNU/Linux 6.0, apt is configured:

```
# squeeze
deb     http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/     squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/     squeeze main contrib non-free
```

I want to install Java 7, but apt does not see it:

```
apt-cache search openjdk
openjdk-6-dbg - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
openjdk-6-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
openjdk-6-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update` after changing the sources list file?

Comment: I have not changed sources. Yes, I have run update many times.

Comment: Friend of mine has upgraded my system to wheezy and then I was able to install JDK7.

Comment: I [checked the package database](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=openjdk-7&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) and found that there are no `openjdk-7` packages for squeeze, only for wheezy.

Comment: @DanD. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I upgraded debian to make it work.